# R: Handling NaN values in t.test

Tags: r, nan

I have many vectors on which I should perform one t-test for each.
each of these vectors contain data relative to two groups, but some values are missing. Fo eaxmple, one of such vectors may be:

```
A <- c(1, NaN, 1.2, 1.5, 5.6, 5.1, 4.8, 4.7)
```

where the factors are in the vector

```
B <- c("CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "TRTD", "TRTD", "TRTD", "TRTD")
```

When performing `t.test(A~B)`, an error is issued... How can I handle this?

Comment: it works for me ... what error do you get?

Comment: Actually, this was just an example, which I just found out works also for me... The problem is when there are more NaNs, in such case there is an error saying "not enough 'y' observations"... I was just wondering whether there is the possibility to return NA instead of an error (I would like to use t.test in a for loop, having many vectors)

Comment: can you edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get is quite informative: it seems you do not have enough observations to compute `t.test`. Your question is however on how to produce `NA`'s instead of errors that break the loops. In this case you can use `tryCatch` or `try` (simplified version of `tryCatch`):

```
tryCatch(t.test(x ~ y), error = function(err) return(NA))
```

in this function you have `expr` argument that is your function, `error` is a function that takes as input *the error message* and outputs anything you want (e.g. `function(err) print(err)` would simply print the error message on the screen) and `warning` takes as input a warning message and works in similar fashion.